# maven cross project integration

Tags: maven, integration-testing

I am new to maven and I am having a little trouble wrapping my head around this.

I have a bunch of Integration tests bundled as a project. I'd like to be able to apply these tests to any other project at will.

How do I get the integration tests project code into another project using the POM and executing during the integration test phase?

If I take it in as a dependency and the Integration test project's POM specifies phase integration-testing. Does the original project's build cycle continue till it reaches integration-testing then the dependency project take over at that phase?

Sorry I feel like I am beating a dead horse here. Your responses have been very helpful in making me understand whats going on and what I need to do.
My question is even if my test code compiles and is added as a dependency with test as the scope for some reason it doesn't execute or detect the test.
The test is named appTest and has the JUnit 4.x tag on it and I can't figure out why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option would be extracting code of integration tests to separate module and then you will have to run `mvn install` to publish binaries to the local repository to be visible when building another project or just `mvn compile` will be required if these tests will be used in the multi-module project where modules have the same version as parent module.
To be used in another project or module it should be declared in dependency section with test scope like junit library.

If above is not suitable option you can try prepare attached jar with test classifier (file name suffix):

```xml
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-jar</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>com/thenewmotion/test/**/*.*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

and to be used in addition to test scope the test-jar type or tests classifier should be added:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thenewmotion</groupId>
    <artifactId>msp-solveconnector</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <type>test-jar</type>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That is essentially what I am asking. How do I do that and still execute the integration tests on other projects?
I appreciate the quick response

Comment: I have tried all three ways you suggested with very simple starter code but the test in the test module/project won't run on the other project. Each time sureFire says there are no tests to be run and moves on.

Any more idea's? The only other one I had was making a custom plugin which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: surefire plugin look for test files which starts of ends the Test prefix or suffix by default, but it can be easy configured by includes and excludes tags: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html

Comment: Also maven-failsafe-plugin that is preferable for integration test have *IT default mask for tests, please see usage page for it: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Here are best books about maven, infrastructure around it and best practices: http://www.sonatype.com/Support/Books

Answer (score 2):

You can publish your tests in an isolate artifact configuring maven-jar-plugin and running **mvn install**:

```xml
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
 <executions>
  <execution>
   <goals>
    <goal>test-jar</goal>
   </goals>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

And later import the dependency from other projects where you want to execute the tests:

```xml
<dependency>
 <groupId>project.with.tests.groupid</groupId>
 <artifactId>projectwithtestsartifatid</artifactId>
 <version>1.0</version>
 <type>test-jar</type>
 <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Anyway, surefire or failsafe plugins only look for tests in **target/test-classes** folder, not in jars from classpath. There is an [open issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-569) about it in surefire with no fixed version assigned (at least by the moment).

A workaround would be to use dependencies plugin to unpack test classes in **target/test-classes**, but this could contaminate the release:

```xml
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
 <executions>
  <execution>
   <id>resource-dependencies</id>
   <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
   <goals>
    <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
   </goals>
   <configuration>
    <includeTypes>test-jar</includeTypes>
    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</outputDirectory>
   </configuration>
  </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```